# jquery text slider next/looping issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having some glitch with the content of the text slider I found. When your on the last slide of the slider (or maybe it always trigger when you clicked on the next arrow) then click on next you should see the first slide but what happens is you see blank slide then it will appear in a blink.

Not so sure what or why is that happening. The effect of the slide should look like when you clicked on the previous button.

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wo8n3y60/) and the reference is [here](https://codepen.io/TyStelmach/pen/yygvNK)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //rotation speed and timer
  var speed = 99999;
  var run = setInterval(rotate, speed);
  var slides = $('.slide');
  var container = $('#slides ul');
  var elm = container.find(':first-child').prop("tagName");
  var item_width = container.width();
  var previous = 'prev'; //id of previous button
  var next = 'next'; //id of next button
  
  slides.width(item_width); //set the slides to the correct pixel width
  container.parent().width(item_width);
  container.width(slides.length * item_width); //set the slides container to the correct total width
  container.find(elm + ':first').before(container.find(elm + ':last'));
  resetSlides();

  //if user clicked on prev button
  $('#buttons a').click(function(e) {
    //slide the item
    if (container.is(':animated')) {
      return false;
    }
    
    if (e.target.id == previous) {
      container.stop().animate({
        'left': 0
      }, 2000, function() {
        container.find(elm + ':first').before(container.find(elm + ':last'));
        resetSlides();
      });
    }

    if (e.target.id == next) {
      container.stop().animate({
        'left': item_width * -2
      }, 2000, function() {
        container.find(elm + ':last').after(container.find(elm + ':first'));
        resetSlides();
      });
    }

    //cancel the link behavior            
    return false;
  });

  //if mouse hover, pause the auto rotation, otherwise rotate it    
  container.parent().mouseenter(function() {
    clearInterval(run);
  }).mouseleave(function() {
    run = setInterval(rotate, speed);
  });

  function resetSlides() {
    //and adjust the container so current is in the frame
    container.css({
      'left': -1 * item_width
    });
  }
});
//a simple function to click next link
//a timer will call this function, and the rotation will begin

function rotate() {
  $('#next').click();
}
```

```css
#slides {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
#slides ul {
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}
#slides li {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  font-family: lato, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="carousel">
  <div class="btn-bar">
    <div id="buttons"><a id="prev" href="#">&lt;</a><a id="next" href="#">&gt;</a> 
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="slides">
    <ul>
      <li class="MonthTreats slide" style="width: 736px;">
        <div class="MonthHeader">
          <h1>slide 1</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="Content">
          <div class="MonthContent">
            <div class="container">
              <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus eu nisl rhoncus, mattis justo cursus, condimentum tortor. Pellentesque porttitor nulla eleifend, suscipit lorem vitae, efficitur ligula. Pellentesque tincidunt nec velit
                sed feugiat. Integer ac dictum libero. Maecenas condimentum augue non leo bibendum, a commodo dolor eleifend. Curabitur faucibus dui sit amet purus ultricies, et blandit lacus euismod. Ut interdum rutrum dictum. Donec sit amet augue vel
                nisi tempus pretium. Maecenas eget risus et justo cursus laoreet in at lorem. Vivamus et ligula ipsum. Nullam eget tortor porttitor, dapibus eros at, pretium augue. Donec pulvinar dignissim massa et interdum.</p>
              <p>Praesent id neque quis lectus varius euismod. Donec rutrum lorem a condimentum pretium. Sed dictum nunc vitae turpis posuere, eu volutpat velit tincidunt. Pellentesque sodales, nisi et vehicula finibus, libero ipsum imperdiet est, quis venenatis
                orci ligula at libero. Nam eleifend orci justo. Mauris enim turpis, iaculis quis sagittis a, vehicula non nisi. Vivamus eget interdum nisi. Vivamus in euismod nunc. Curabitur aliquam quam ac neque condimentum, nec consequat nisi mattis.
                Curabitur ac urna eu augue semper porta sit amet sed orci. Suspendisse facilisis urna id ligula auctor vestibulum. Vivamus sed hendrerit ipsum, euismod imperdiet elit. Maecenas non iaculis nulla.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="MonthTreats slide" style="width: 736px;">
        <div class="MonthHeader">
          <h1>slide 2</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="Content">
          <div class="MonthContent">
            <div class="container">
              <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus eu nisl rhoncus, mattis justo cursus, condimentum tortor. Pellentesque porttitor nulla eleifend, suscipit lorem vitae, efficitur ligula. Pellentesque tincidunt nec velit
                sed feugiat. Integer ac dictum libero. Maecenas condimentum augue non leo bibendum, a commodo dolor eleifend. Curabitur faucibus dui sit amet purus ultricies, et blandit lacus euismod. Ut interdum rutrum dictum. Donec sit amet augue vel
                nisi tempus pretium. Maecenas eget risus et justo cursus laoreet in at lorem. Vivamus et ligula ipsum. Nullam eget tortor porttitor, dapibus eros at, pretium augue. Donec pulvinar dignissim massa et interdum.</p>
              <p>Praesent id neque quis lectus varius euismod. Donec rutrum lorem a condimentum pretium. Sed dictum nunc vitae turpis posuere, eu volutpat velit tincidunt. Pellentesque sodales, nisi et vehicula finibus, libero ipsum imperdiet est, quis venenatis
                orci ligula at libero. Nam eleifend orci justo. Mauris enim turpis, iaculis quis sagittis a, vehicula non nisi. Vivamus eget interdum nisi. Vivamus in euismod nunc. Curabitur aliquam quam ac neque condimentum, nec consequat nisi mattis.
                Curabitur ac urna eu augue semper porta sit amet sed orci. Suspendisse facilisis urna id ligula auctor vestibulum. Vivamus sed hendrerit ipsum, euismod imperdiet elit. Maecenas non iaculis nulla.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You take a piece of code on internet you don't look how it works and how it's build and you post an issue on stack ?

Comment: I can understand simple js not this kind of levels.

Comment: It seems to working from 3 slides and up

Comment: is this the line that makes the slider go all around when 2 slides are only available?  `'left': item_width * -2`

Comment: Basically I'm going to use this that's why I'm testing it. And for some reason the slides that I have are only 2 slides and this doesn't work accordingly with 2 slides. If i can fix this I won't bother posting it in here. That's why I came here.